# Hazelcast cluster.timediff metric unit

Tags: hazelcast

Here is the full HealthMonitor output:

> .HealthMonitor; [xxx/com/hazelcast/internal/diagnostics/HealthMonitor]; [3.8] processors=12, physical.memory.total=31.1G, physical.memory.free=1.2G, swap.space.total=15.7G, swap.space.free=15.7G, heap.memory.used=181.1M, heap.memory.free=74.9M, heap.memory.total=256.0M, heap.memory.max=256.0M, **heap.memory.used/total=70.75%, heap.memory.used/max=70.75%**, minor.gc.count=2626, minor.gc.time=27401ms, major.gc.count=0, major.gc.time=0ms, load.process=0.00%, load.system=0.38%, load.systemAverage=549.00%, thread.count=91, thread.peakCount=177, **cluster.timeDiff=-242516**, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=15118896, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, operations.pending.invocations.count=0, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=20, client.connection.count=0, connection.count=15;

---

## Question:

**What does the metric cluster.timeDiff in the HealthMonitor output tell?**
Is it an indication, that NTP (clock synchronization between cluster members) is missing?

I couldn't find any specifics in the hazelcast docu about cluster.timeDiff. Neither for the applied version [[3.8]](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html) nor for the latest stable version [[4.1.1]](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/management/health-check-monitoring.html)

**e.g. cluster.timeDiff=-242516**
EDIT: according to other logs below this must be ms, therefore the cluster.timeDiff is around 4 minutes in the cluster at question.

> 2021-03-06T08:16:39,495; WARN; [xxx/com/hazelcast/internal/cluster/impl/ClusterHeartbeatManager]; [x.x.x.x]:5701 [xxx] [3.8] Ignoring heartbeat from Member [x.x.x.x]:5724 - 0a519310-ac9f-4085-b38d-aa7a7ec8ff1f lite since it is expired (now: 2021-03-06 08:12:36.979, timestamp: 2021-03-06 08:11:32.385);

The log statement time (from the JVM) is around 4 minutes later, than the "now" timestamp... which makes me believe cluster.timeDiff is in ms.

---

Besides it would be good to know, if cluster.timeDiff is

- the longest difference between any two members in the whole cluster? OR
- the longest difference between this member and another member?

*I hope the difference between those two options is clear*

---

Note that the system also reports about members missing their heartbeat intervals (leading to removal of members) and clock jumps, which makes me suspicious that **cluster.timeDiff=-242516** might be a seriously high value.

> [xxx/com/hazelcast/internal/cluster/impl/ClusterHeartbeatManager]; [x.x.x.x]:5701 [3.8] Resetting heartbeat timestamps because of huge system clock jump! Clock-Jump: 37000 ms, Heartbeat-Timeout: 30000 ms;